# Spring Integration Error - Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-integration

Getting error,

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:.myGatewayChannel'.
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

Code,

```
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway;


@Component
public class MyOutboundGateway
{

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myGatewayChannel")
    public JmsOutboundGateway jmsGateway()
    {
        final JmsOutboundGateway jmsOutboundGateway = new JmsOutboundGateway();
        jmsOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(this.getConnectionFactory());

        final ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        final Expression requestDestinationExpression = parser.parseExpression("payload.requestQueue");
        jmsOutboundGateway.setRequestDestinationExpression(requestDestinationExpression);
        final Expression replyDestinationExpression = parser.parseExpression("payload.responseQueue");
        jmsOutboundGateway.setReplyDestinationExpression(replyDestinationExpression);
        // jmsOutboundGateway.setCorrelationKey("JMSCorrelationID");
        jmsOutboundGateway.setExtractRequestPayload(true);
        return jmsOutboundGateway;
    }

    public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory()
    {
        final String brokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616";
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);

        final PooledConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setCreateConnectionOnStartup(false);
        connectionFactory.setMaxConnections(1);
        connectionFactory.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(1);
        connectionFactory.setIdleTimeout(10);

        connectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);

        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

My spring-context.xml,

```
<int:channel id="myGatewayChannel" />

<int:gateway id="myMessageServiceGateway"
    service-interface="MyMessageServiceGateway"
    default-request-channel="myGatewayChannel" />
```

I am using following pom dependency,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Could you please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JmsOutboundGateway` and the `ConnectionFactory` for it must be declared as beans.

Even if `MyOutboundGateway` is scanned as a component, there is no guaranty that `@ServiceActivator` populates proper endpoint for the `myGatewayChannel`.

Please, revise your architecture and check if you really have the `<context:component-scan>` to populate beans for the `@Component` and similar.